# Enabling NX Computation Caching causes library to fail in the build

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

recently we upgraded our NX monorepo from 8.x to the latest 12.9 version. After the upgrade, the build process takes forever but completes successfully. If we enable the Computation Caching feature in NX to reduce the time taken to build some of the libraries do not complete the build and exit without showing an error or success message (which is correctly visible in case Computation caching is disabled).
I tried to run the builds with `--verbose` flag but there is no additional information visible. Currently, we are performing the builds by disabling the Computation caching and no one is happy about it.

Output screenshot with Computation caching enabled:
[image]

Output screenshot with computation caching disabled:
[image]

I opened a bug on NX you can refer it over [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/7303)

The output of `nx report` command:

```
NX Report complete - copy this into the issue template

Node : 14.17.6
OS : win32 x64
npm : 6.14.15

nx : 12.9.0
@nrwl/angular : 12.9.0
@nrwl/cli : 12.9.0
@nrwl/cypress : 12.9.0
@nrwl/devkit : 12.9.0
@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : 12.9.0
@nrwl/express : 12.9.0
@nrwl/jest : 12.9.0
@nrwl/linter : 12.9.0
@nrwl/nest : Not Found
@nrwl/next : Not Found
@nrwl/node : 12.9.0
@nrwl/nx-cloud : Not Found
@nrwl/react : Not Found
@nrwl/schematics : 8.12.11
@nrwl/tao : 12.9.0
@nrwl/web : Not Found
@nrwl/workspace : 12.9.0
@nrwl/storybook : 12.9.0
@nrwl/gatsby : Not Found
typescript : 4.1.5
```

Would really appreciate any feedback or insights into what could be causing this.

Comment: None if your links work - which makes it a bit complicated..

Comment: @MikeOne I edited the issue multiple times to get the links working, however, it just shows up like this. I will retry it again.

Comment: edited to get the screenshots working.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but did you try to clear the cache? nx clear-cache

Comment: yes i have tried to clear cache, even removed node_modules, npm_cache, .npm, tried with  node 12.x and 14.x  but all things just lead to the build exiting.